# How to return the Result Set in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, resultset

I am trying to return a resultset of a given student id and show the gpa. However it is saying I am not able to do the operation when the result set is closed. This is my code:

```
/**
 * Returns a ResultSet with a row containing the computed GPA (named as gpa) for a given student id.
 * You must use a PreparedStatement.
 * 
 * @return
 *       ResultSet containing computed GPA
 */
public ResultSet computeGPA(String studentId) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rst;

     // TODO: Use a PreparedStatement
    try(Connection con = connect()){

        String sql = "SELECT gpa FROM student WHERE sid=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, studentId);
        rst = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rst.next()){
            System.out.println(rst.getString("gpa"));
        }
    }
    return rst;
}
```

This is the result im getting

> Connecting to database.
>   2.96 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getMetaData(ResultSetImpl.java:3107)     at
>   EnrollJDBC.resultSetToString(EnrollJDBC.java:500)     at
>   EnrollJDBC.main(EnrollJDBC.java:59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the (prepared) statement is closed, also its result sets are closed.
This is understandable as ResultSet is a heavy class, with metadata and all.

Return a more specific list.

```
public List<String> computeGPA(String studentId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT gpa FROM student WHERE sid=?";
    try (Connection con = connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, studentId);
        try (ResultSet rst = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
            List<String> gpas = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rst.next()) {
                gpas.add(rst.getString(1));
            }
            return gpas;
        }
    }
}
```

The second try-with-resources is officially not needed as said, but code checkers will notice that ResultSet is Autocloseable, and might give a false positive warning.

Comment: Well, what if the rows aren't Strings but of different types, what then?

Comment: @Freddy I used the OP's types and the error `Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed` indicates that they probably are okay. `setLong(1, longId)` for other cases.

Answer (score 3):

You use `try-with-resources` which closes `Connection` when your `try` block is done. In Java when you close `Connection` you also automatically close all `ResultSet` objects associated with that connection. And that is what exception tells you. You are trying to use closed `ResultSet`. So you need to change your code to close connection only when `ResultSet` is fully processed.

Since you execute `SELECT` by id you get either one record or no records. So why not to return that only value if it exists or `null` (or empty string) if student with such id doesn't exists instead of returning `ResultSet` object from `computeGPA()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return ResultSet because it will be closed when method destroyed. But you can get raw data from ResultSet, try this:

```
public ArrayList<Byte[]> getResultQuery(String query){
    ArrayList<Byte[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Byte[] row;
    conn = getConnection(db_url);
    try {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        int countColumn = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        if (countColumn==0) return null;
        while (resultSet.next()){
            row = new Byte[countColumn];
            for (int i = 0; i<countColumn; i++){
                row[i] = resultSet.getByte(i+1);
            }
            arrayList.add(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public static Connection getConnection (String db_url){
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

In this, i try to return ArrayList of Byte[], 1 Byte[] = 1 row in ResultSet. If you want to get some value, just convert Byte[i] to your datatype you want!